# Ajax_pagination gem loading image missing in Rails 4 production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was using [this gem](https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination) successfully in production until moving to Rails 4. Now the loading image is not working properly. I have reached out to the developer, without assistance, so I would like to ask your help on this one.

Here is the file which I believe is involved:

https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination/blob/1297da84ead61f206e30f3d6bae2da6a551fed14/lib/generators/ajax_pagination/assets_generator.rb

Can this repo be modified to correctly show the image in Rails 4?

At the moment, I'm just seeing a broken image link.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was simple in the end I just downloaded the original image:

https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination/blob/master/lib/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif

and put it into my existing assets/images directory! Bingo!